# Why Error object can print pure string message

Tags: javascript, prototype

**I don't want to inherit or extend from the `Error` so don't mark my question is duplicate if the solution you post is inherit or extend from `Error`**

Below is my sample code and run on Chrome. Comments below `console.log` is output from Chrome developer tool's console tab.

What I want to know is why the `Error` object can output the raw string message but my `CustomError` will output a object.

Is it possible to implement an object like the `Error` object can output the raw string message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>
    function CustomError() {
      this.message = "MyErrorMessage";
    }

    var nativeError = new Error();
    var customError = new CustomError();

    console.log(nativeError);
    // Error

    console.log(customError);
    // CustomError {message: "MyErrorMessage"}

    Error.prototype.message = "Modify native error prototype message";
    var nativeErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage = new Error();
    console.log(nativeErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage);
    // Error: Modify native error prototype message

    CustomError.prototype.message = "Modify custom error prototype message";
    customErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage;
    var customErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage = new CustomError();
    console.log(customErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage);
    // CustomError {message: "MyErrorMessage"}

    customErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage.__proto__.message =
      "Modify custom error prototype message";

    console.log(customErrorAfterModifyPrototypeMessage);
    //index.html:37 CustomError {message: "MyErrorMessage"}
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: "*I want to know is why the Error object can output the raw string message*" - simply because instances of `Error` are treated specially by the console, using `.toString()` for formatting. If you want this behaviour, you must inherit from `Error`.

Comment: Do you mean is ```not possible``` to do what I want if I don't want to inherit from ```Error``` because this is control by Chrome and oculd I find this part of source code in Chrome source code?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (The source code of the dev tools, to be precise)

Comment: Is form ```toString()``` or ```message```? but I think in the ```toString``` it call the ```message```?

Comment: Yes, `Error.prototype.toString` prints the name of the error constructor and the message property.

Comment: Thank you bro but sad to hear that I can't implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always override `console.log` and do the special treatment for `CustomError` yourself.

```js
function CustomError(message = "") {
    this.message = message;
    //override toString to just return your message (or whatever you want your output to look like)
    this.toString = () => this.message;
}

const ce = new CustomError("some message");

//this shows the builtin behaviour of console.log
console.log(ce);

//preserve the original console.log function, we'll need it later on
console.originalLog = console.log;

//override console.log with a new function
console.log = function() {
    //check if any of the arguments is a CustomError
    //and replace CustomErrors with its string representation
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if (arguments[i] && arguments[i].constructor.name === "CustomError") 
            arguments[i] = arguments[i].toString();

    //call the original log function with the updated arguments
    console.originalLog.apply(this, arguments);
}

//this shows the overriden behaviour of console.log
console.log(ce);

//and back to original behaviour again
console.log = console.originalLog;
console.originalLog = undefined;
console.log(ce);
```

Probably not the most efficient or elegant solution, but it gets the job done in most scenarios. It won't work, if the `CustomError` is nested inside another object or array.

Make sure to preserve the original behaviour of `console.log` in another variable, so you can use it, once you modified the `arguments`.

Comment: A small question is why need ```back to original behaviour again```

Comment: You don't really *need* it. It's there just to demonstrate how it's done, if you want to revert the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because instances of Error are treated specially by the console, using `.toString()` for formatting. If you want this behaviour, you must inherit from Error

The source code of the dev tools

The answer from comment by @Berg

Comment: see my answer on how to override `console.log` to get your desired behaviour